# Can you raise your original body as an undead after moving to a clone?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, undead, necromancy

In the situation where you have a currently mature clone from the *Clone* spell, die, transfer to your clone, and then manage to go back and recover your previous body, is that body potentially a candidate for becoming an undead minion, such as with the *Create Undead* spell?

Comment: Related: [The 5e Ethical Necromancer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/104093/11402) - Disclaimer: I'm the Q author.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### You should be able to raise your own, other, body.

Clone only states that your other body is "inert and cannot be brought back to life", not that it is no longer a corpse.

The requirement for Create Undead?

> You can cast this spell only at night. Choose up to three corpses of Medium or Small humanoids within range. Each corpse becomes a ghoul under your control.

So, our checklist looks something like this:

- 6th level spell slot? [check]
- one corpse? [check]

**You are the proud new owner of a screaming, howling, baby clone ghoul abomination.**

Comment: ...that looks like an older version of yourself.

Comment: Is it appropriate to give out cigars in a case like this?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast [Fire bad!](https://imgur.com/gallery/2qFmazO)

Comment: @NautArch That movie is a gold mine of relatable quotes/vignettes.

Answer (score 22):

## Disturbingly possible

When your soul leaves your body to go into the [Clone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/clone), the following happens to the original (emphasis mine):

> The original creature's physical remains, if they still exist, **become inert and can't thereafter be restored to life**, since the creature's soul is elsewhere.

[Create Undead](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/create-undead) simply states:

> Choose up to three corpses of Medium or Small humanoids within range.

Create Undead is not restoring life, it is creating undead. Undead does not equate to alive (as restore to life generally is referring to Revivify, Resurrect, etc.)

**In this case, you may visit your old body and make it a Ghoul.**

Comment: You can even name it after a movie star ... for example, [Elliot Ghoul(d)](https://en.mediamass.net/people/elliott-gould/deathhoax.html)

Comment: Somehow, I still suspect that "become inert" means "become something other than a corpse", because a corpse isn't something that is normally inert.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Really? The corpses I make are all inert. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @GMJoe wouldn't 'ert a fly.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Well, it can't be brought back to life implies it's not alive.  But if it's not a corpse then it's not dead.  Which means the body is...undead?  Ergo, we conclude that you cannot make your previous body a ghoul, because it already is one.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy I'm alive, so I can't be brought *back* to life, so I'm not alive?

Comment: @RobertColumbia I believe that inert most certainly does *not* mean corpse here. Inert means chemically inactive. Corpses are chemically active (they decompose), so I think you are left with a perfectly preserved object that looks like a corpse, but isn't.

Comment: @MichaelW that's exactly what I meant. A corpse decays - it isn't inert. An inert corpse-substitute isn't really a corpse.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Inert means chemically inactive in the field of chemistry. In other contexts, it has other meanings: A person on the verge of death due to starvation would be inert, for example, if they lacked the strength to move. Since the clone spell doesn't otherwise reference chemistry, I'm not convinced that the chemistry definition of the word is the one being used here.