# If you cast Reincarnation on a body, can you still cast Speak with Dead on it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, reincarnation

In this scenario a person that has been dead for less than 10 days is *Reincarnate*d. Their old body is still there. Someone then casts *Speak with Dead* on the body.

Question: Would the *Speak with Dead* spell work?

Comment: Related: [Can you raise your original body as an undead after moving to a clone?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/123659/can-you-raise-your-original-body-as-an-undead-after-moving-to-a-clone)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Yes

[*Speak with dead*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/speak-with-dead) clearly states that:

> This spell doesn't return the creature's soul to its body, only its animating spirit.

Which comes to mean that the corpse itself is animated as a sort of puppet, retaining the memories it organically had while it lived. Since this is separate from the soul, the now reincarnated guy wouldn't even know this was happening.

Comment: That could be an interesting plot - someone desperate to retrieve or destroy their old body before secret information can be extracted from it...

Comment: Does the new body get a new spirit?

Comment: Hello @Overthinks, not really, it gets a 'animating spirit', but from the wording I think it's more like a foreign magical entity rather than something native to the corpse.

Comment: @user3631225 the spirit has all the knowledge of the person when they were alive. This still seems kinda weird.